# Bootstrap dropdown: change dropdown icon when it's active?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following setup:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="item in navigationBar.navObject.items" class="btn-group">
  <button data-ng-class="{current: $last}" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" type="button" data-ng-click="navigationBar.goToState(item)"> {{item.name}}</button>
  <button data-ng-hide="item.isTerminal" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-default btn-xs dropdown-toggle" type="button">
     <span class="fa fa-fw fa-caret-right"></span>                        
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li data-ng-repeat="subItem in item.subItems"><a data-ng-click="subItem.item.goToState()">{{subItem.name}}</a></li>               
  </ul>
</div>
```

And I would like the icon in the dropdown to change from fa-caret-right to fa-caret-down when the dropdown list is visible. Is there any way to do this strictly with CSS?

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to change the attributes of HTML elements using CSS, you'll probably want to use jQuery instead.

Bootstrap has some nifty JavaScript going on, where you can execute your own scripts when boostrap elements inside your website is used.

Initialize dropdown using this inside jQuery.

`$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();`

When it's called you can hook different actions to it using the handles specified on the bootstrap docs.
on('show.bs.dropdown', function(){}); is just a fancy word for saying "on dropdown"

`$('.dropdown-toggle').on('show.bs.dropdown', function () {
    // All actions to fire after the dropdown is shown go here.
    $('.fa .fa-fw').addClass('fa-caret-right');
    $('.fa .fa-fw').removeClass('fa-caret-down'); 
})`

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I was looking for this solution and have one that works for me.  You can target and change the pseudo element inside that span.  When you click the button, doesn't the button add an `open` class?  So, then the css would look like:

```
btn.open .fa-caret-right:before { content: "\e114"; }
```

Use the `.open` added to the button class.
The `\e114` being the character of the down arrow.